# Is there an easy way to persist authentication data in angular

Tags: angular, authentication

So I've been working on an angular project of mine and have been really struggling with the authentication part, more specifically the persistence of auth data.

Thus far I've managed to login, logout and put a route guard in place. The issue is that once I reload the page on a "guarded" route, I have to log in again. If I use the routerLink however, I can go to the page without any need for logging in.

Right now, when I log in successfully, a JWT token is generated and stored in a cookie. Back in the angular app, a "BehaviorSubject" variable called "isAuthenticated" is set to true and the user is being redirected to a "guarded" page. On refresh, I would like to check whether or not someone is authenticated by calling an API endpoint which checks the validity of the jwt cookie. I use "CanActivate" as a guard which checks whether the value of "isAuthenticated" is true. If so, the user can access locked pages, if not, not.

I know the issue results from the "login redirect" being directly connected to "isAuthenticated" as it starts of as false and isn't being set to true in time using above mentioned API endpoint.

Any ideas? All are welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered updating CanActivate to return a promise or observable (that async checks the api endpoint) and then as a side effect update the behavior subject?

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! Thanks so much for the quick and on point response @AlexanderStaroselsky !